# No such module 'GoogleMobileAds' in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, admob

[image]

I did every solution from web search..

As you see the image, GoogleMobileAds.framework is included well.
But I can't build project with 'No such module 'GoogleMobileAds'' error

What should I try?

p.s. what I did additionally

Build Settings

- Other Linker Flags : $(OTHER_LDFLAGS) -ObjC
- Always Search User Paths : YES
- Framework Search Paths : $(inherited)

Add import AppDelegate

- import Firebase

p.s. I'm trying to integrate without CocoaPods

Comment: Are you sure you have to put `import`?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Do you mean just remove the import code? Then I get these errors "use of undeclared type 'GADBannerView'", "Use of unresolved identifier 'FIRApp'", "Use of unresolved identifier 'GADMobileAds'" and so on...

Comment: I would suggest to do cocoapods, just give it a try...

Comment: It works without cocoapods.. How you imported GoogleMobileAds? Did you selected option to include in project? If you don't select that option you get above error

Comment: *Other Linker Flags : $(OTHER_LDFLAGS) -ObjC* this is not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 16):

You need to make sure the framework is included in your targets Build Phases. Target>Build Phases>Link Binary With Libraries. If it is not there click the "+" sign to add it.

[image]

Comment: When I click the "+" sign, GoogleMobileAds is not in the list

Comment: @Curtis make sure you added it on pod  ->   pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'

Answer (score 9):

I have faced the exact same issue. Running the following command in Terminal solved it for me:

```
pod install --repo-update
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you don't need CocoaPods.

1. Just remove the framework from your project's hierarchy.
2. Find the `GoogleMobileAds.framework` file you just unzipped and simply drag and drop it into the navigator (the view on the left that shows you all the files in your project)
3. Make sure to check "Copy items if needed" and select the "Create groups" option when prompted.

Works like a charm to me.

Comment: Now that I have to use AdMob 8.1 I get "ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'FBLPromises'" It is there in Link Binary With Libraries.

Answer (score 3):

If installed with "pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'", remove it from pod file, run pod install, then add it back, run pod install again. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Podfile file contains the following libs

```
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
```

Maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me also in Xcode 14.2 using Swift 5.

I resolved it by removing the package(SPM) and then re-adding it again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I would suggest using the cocoapods. If you want to integrate the SDK manually, copy the framework to the root directory and then move it to the Frameworks folder later. It seemed to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open application prefenences and link this framework into your project. check'embedded framworks' and framework path too.

https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start

read this manual

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution 
just add "GoogleMobileAds" to your project holder 
then open Build Phases choose Link Binary With Libraries and press + and choose "Add other..." find in your project holder "GoogleMobileAds" and ad it 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnPvf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Remember there are two places to update when you add/replace/move a framework:

- Under build phases be sure to add the framework to the list of libraries to link with
- For the target (not the project) add the directory containing the framework to the "Framework Search Paths" list of directories if it is not already present (for example, if you placed the framework in a path not previously containing frameworks)