# Xcode 14.3 - I'm using SPM with firebase. I keep getting No such module 'FirebaseFirestore'

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

All of my packages are added, but for some reason the only feature of Firebase that gives me a problem is Firestore. I'm using Swift Package Manager. Let me know if I am doing anything wrong. Thank you.

The error message related to `import FirebaseFirestore`:

```
No such module 'FirebaseFirestore'
```

My packages:
[image]

I have tried installing and reinstalling, cleaning the project, restarting xcode and my laptop and going back in. this was not resolved.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76209805/13839521

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/158pccp/xcode_143_not_sure_if_i_am_missing_something_here/